# Add posts to Jekyll index page, without .md files

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I would like to write a generator plugin to add some post-like items to my blog. The items are supposed to appear in the blog index, but they have no page associated to them (you can't click on them).

I know I need something like

```
class QuoteGenerator < Generator
  safe true

  def generate(site)
    # add a single post
    site.posts << QuotePost.new(site, site.source, "Blub")
  end
end
```

But what I don't understand is how to implement my `Post` subclass. I've found that other plugins (like [this one to embed Flickr photos](https://github.com/lawmurray/indii-jekyll-flickr/blob/master/indii-jekyll-flickr.rb)) write the data they want to a markdown+YAML file, and then reference this file:

```
class QuotePost < Post
  def initialize(site, base, title)
    # Nooo, I don't want to create a .md file for this
    name = "2016-05-13-test.md"
    dir = ""
    # (write out .md file here)
    super(site, base, dir, name)
  end
end
```

But then, I would hardly need a Plugin in the first place. I could just generate the markdown files myself (with an external script).

What I'd like to do is to just set a couple of variables in my Post subclass, and have them available in the template for the blog index. How can I do that?

Comment: Why don't you use a collection with `output: false` ? Where the datas come from ?

Answer (score 0):

The case you've described looks to be unrelated to `Post`, since usual posts are file-based. Collections may be suitable, but again - that's not clear how you getting the content.

I'd suggest two major options:

1. Use _data/ to set an object list, where each item has the required properties if you can define them via a static JSON/CSV/etc file (or generate it once, to separate external data producer and jekyll visualization).
2. Use :pre_render [hook](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/#hooks) and a plugin if you have to define the data via code -

> your hook will also receive a payload hash as a second parameter which allows you full control over the variables that are available while rendering

Having your data in `site.data` variable allows you to iterate through items, render something or include a  template and so on. Also there are plugins which generate new pages based on site's data.

The right answer depends on how you're getting the content, which markup you need and how those items will be used.